# How to resolve Japanese characters in file name while adding attachments in javax.mail.Message?

Tags: java, file, email, encoding, mime

I'm generating emails as EML files for testing something I'm working on. For thorough testing, I also need to check the functionality in cases where we have email with attachments which have Japanese names. Here's a small sample:[image: files that will be added as attachments]

I'm using **javax.mail.Message** for creating emails.

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(Session.getInstance(System.getProperties()));
message.setFrom(from);
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, StringUtil.arrFromAddressArrayList(to));
message.setSubject(subject);
content.setText(body);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

multipart.addBodyPart(content);
message.setContent(multipart);
```

Now I use following lines to add the attachment. Here, **attachmentFile** is a String containing path of the file I want to add.

```
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentFile);
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachment.setFileName(new File(attachmentFile).getName());
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
```

Though this works fine for normal emails, it puts underscore characters in places that contain Japanese characters.

After spending some time on stackoverflow, I made the following change:

```
attachment.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(new File(attachmentFile).getName(), "UTF-8", null));
```

This helped with the Kanji characters but fails with standard hiragana or katakana alphabet.[image: Japanese Characters]

This images shows that the one containing English + Kanji text comes perfectly fine while the other one fails.

[image: Attachments in the email]

What should be done about it?

Edit:
File names copied as string:

ExportedHTML_ファイルメーカー_MacEng

評価版お読みください

Eng日本語

Comment: What if you try a different `chartset` like `ISO-2022-JP`

Comment: @Hackerman tried this one. Doesn't help. Appends some extra kanji characters to that file, while doesn't resolve hiragana and katakana. How can I find which charset these file names use?

Comment: That it seems to be the root cause of your issue. Once you have the right charset, everything should works as expected. Let me do some research

Comment: Can you add to the question one hiragana and one katakana filename as string in order to do some testing on my side?

Comment: Added the text. This seems so weird. Browsers/Apps are able to handle these so well, yet while programming they are such a headache.